# Converting shapefile to WKT file

Tags: shapefile, qgis-plugins, convert, well-known-text

I have one country layer in a shapefile consisting of a lot of attributes, but the result needs to be in WKT file/format. I'm using QGIS 3.12 . I'd tried GetWKT Plugin but it limited to one selected feature only.

How can I convert the whole shapefile to a WKT file? Any suggestion of what plugins I can use to convert the shapefile?

Comment: WKT is not a file format but a vector representation format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) so you cant really convert a shapefile to WKT but you can add  WKT attribute  to your shape file or any other export format, see @30184 answer for exporting to CSV with WKT

Answer (score 5):

You do not need any plugin. Use Save As... and select CSV as outputformat. From the CSV layer options select "AS_WKT" for the geometry.

[image]